# Octave syntax highlighting in Jupyter notebook

Tags: octave, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, codemirror

I'm running the octave kernel in Jupyter, but I'm not getting syntax highlighting in the code cells.  I've installed Jupyter et. al. through Anaconda.  I can't remember how I got the octave kernel installed, but probably from here:
https://github.com/calysto/octave_kernel

Do I need to do something in the kernel spec to flip on CodeMirror support?

Comment: Did you ever get this one figured out? I'm bumping into a similar issue with the ijavascript kernel.

Comment: I haven't, but I also haven't tried in quite some time.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: turns out the syntax highlighting appeared after refreshing the notebook page, even without the config entry.

Leaving the answer in case it helps with other issues that people might be facing.

---

I managed to get syntax highlighting working for Octave by following the instructions here:
[Configuring the notebook frontend](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frontend_config.html)
configuring the [CodeMirror mode](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#option_mode) to Octave: `"mode": "octave"`

### TL;DR

Put the following code snippet in `~/.jupyter/nbconfig/notebook.json`. (If the file/directory structure is not present then create as required).

```
{
  "CodeCell": {
    "cm_config": {
      "mode": "octave"
    }
  }
}
```

### Caveats

I haven't tested this fully, but it seems the syntax highlighting will persist even for other languages, e.g. Python. This means that the config file might need to be disabled/deleted when using Jupyter for non-Octave notebooks.
Also, I noticed the syntax highlighting doesn't immediately show up on first load of the notebook. I had to refresh the page before it appeared.